# what version of java does ebean 8.1.1 support

Tags: ebean

I am deploying a jersey app with maven which uses ebean 8.1.1. I want to confirm which version of java does ebean 8.1.1 use/support. Our prod is only java 1.6.

Thanks in advance

P.S: Could not find anything in the documentation or anywhere on stackoverflow so asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebean currently supports java 6 and up.

... ***BUT*** there is a danger here in this type of question in not engaging the Ebean community via the google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ebean

For example, the supported version of Java has been raised and discussed there in the past and I'll be raising it again shortly with the view to dropping support for java 6 and 7 and moving to a minimum of java 8.  If you don't engage with the community then you won't be part of that discussion.

That is, posting to stack overflow is not "engaging the Ebean community" per say.

Cheers, Rob.